# changing the default row size in a QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtableview

How do you change the default row size in a QTableView so it is smaller? I can call `resizeRowsToContents()`, but then subsequent inserts still add new rows at the end which are the default size.

I am guessing it might have something to do with style sheets but I'm not familiar enough with what things impact the visual changes.

I am using PySide in Python, but I think this is a general Qt question.

---

example view:

default table appearance

[image]

what the table looks like after `resizeRowsToContents()`:

[image]

now if I add a new blank row at the end:

[image]

Darn, it uses the default row height, with all that extra space.

Comment: `tableView.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)` seems to works nicely, but it's dynamic and slows down my application when I'm doing lots of realtime updates. I really just want to get the standard row size. :-(

Comment: The "standard" row height is what you get when you don't resize to contents. It's based on the size hint for the row, which is derived from the size hint for the item delegate (amongst other things). If you don't like that specific height, just change it to something more acceptable (e.g. `table.fontMetrics().height() + 6`).

Comment: Somehow I don't see a big difference between the second and third image.

Comment: Look at the last blank row (below "toves")

Comment: For anyone stumped by Jason's comment: the method in question is `setSectionResizeMode`, not `setResizeMode`.

Answer (score 14):

`Qt::SizeHintRole` responsible for width and height of cell. So you can just:

```
someModel.setData(someIndex,QSize(width, height), Qt::SizeHintRole);
```

Or just this:

```
someView.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(10);
```

And I think that `setDefaultSectionSize` is exactly what are you looking for. AFAIK there is no another simple way.

[From doc:](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qheaderview.html#setDefaultSectionSize)

> defaultSectionSize : int
>
> This property holds the default size of the header sections before
>   resizing.   This property only affects sections that have Interactive
>   or Fixed as their resize mode.

If you don't know how much pixels you need, then try to get this height after applying `resizeRowsToContents()` with `rowHeight()`

So it should be something like:

```
resizeRowsToContents();
someView.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(someView.rowHeight(0));
```

Comment: Hmmm... but I don't know the number of pixels. I just want the QTableView to display the data without the extra space.

Comment: @JasonS After your screenshot I can see, that row height is same, so I edited my answer and if data is not very complex, it should work.